# How to configure SES to invoke a lambda function in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I have my own email address `abc@xyz.com`. When mail is received in it's inbox (abc@xyz.com), it should trigger lambda function.

So for this use case, I have entered email address `abc@xyz.com` as recipient condition in SES email receiving rule set. Then I tried sending a mail to `abc@xyz.com` from different mail id but lambda is not getting invoked. Please advice.

Comment: May be worth setting SNS action in your receipt rule for more visibility as you can subscribe multiple consumers, yourself by email and Lambda for example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had to create identity with identity type as Domain (I verified that I owned the domain used DKIM so that SES will receive emails which are sent to my domain) and set email receiving receipt rules to invoke lambda function when the domain I own receive the mails.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-setting-up.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-action-lambda.html